# The values are not replacing with new values

Tags: javascript

[image: Even if I add a new city it shows the weather of the previous cities I have searched]

firstly, when I search for any city it shows the weather correctly, but when I try to search for another city/country  It shows the details of the same city that I have searched for before. I think there is something wrong with my JavaScript code. I think the new values that I'm fetching from the API are not getting replaced by the old values.

```
let enterCity = document.querySelector("#enterCity");
let city = document.querySelector(".city");
let country = document.querySelector(".country");
let temp = document.querySelector(".temp");
let text = document.querySelector(".text");

let inputVal = enterCity.value;
// the base url
let url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=${inputVal}&key=cb58be19d0d2****************`;


fetch(url).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
}).then((data) => {
    let search = document.querySelector(".search");
    search.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let container = document.querySelector(".container");

        card = document.createElement("div");
        card.className = "card";
        city = document.createElement("h2");
        city.className = "city";
```

***The problems are with the innerText down below ***

```
        city.innerText = data.location.name;
        country = document.createElement("h5");
        country.className = "country";
        country.innerText = data.location.country;
        temp = document.createElement("h4");
        temp.className = "temp";
        temp.innerText = data.current.temp_c;
        span1 = document.createElement("span");
        span1.id = "deg";
        span1.innerText = "°C"
        temp.appendChild(span1);
        icon = document.createElement("img");
        icon.className = "icon";
        icon.src = data.current.condition.icon;
        text = document.createElement("h3");
        text.className = "text";
        text.innerText = data.current.condition.text;


        card.appendChild(city);
        card.appendChild(country);
        card.appendChild(temp);
        card.appendChild(icon);
        card.appendChild(text);

        container.appendChild(card);
```

Here, I have also cleared the input value
that I'm taking from the user

```
        enterCity.value = "";
    });

});
```

Comment: let city = document.querySelector(".city"); and city = document.createElement("h2"); variable name is same so can you try with different name ? similar in country also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let search = document.querySelector(".search");
    search.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let enterCity = document.querySelector("#enterCity");
        let city = document.querySelector(".city");
        let country = document.querySelector(".country");
        let temp = document.querySelector(".temp");
        let text = document.querySelector(".text");
        var inputVal = enterCity.value;
        // the base url
        let url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=${inputVal}&key=cb58be19d0d2********************`;


        fetch(url).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {
           //Do the remaining works here
        })
    });
```

The actual problem was already assigned the value of `document.querySelector("#enterCity");`  when the page loads instead of on click. So value of enterCity was not changing when you click the search button.

> Note : If the key you given in the question is your personal API key,
> then please try to change it in the console, because it is not good
> idea to publish it in the outside.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening beacause you haven't added onchange event listener on your input(enter city).if you don't add onchange event this will take only your inital value.

So add a onchange listener then call fetch api inside of it.

**Dummy example -**

```js
let entercity=document.querySelector("#entercity");

     entercity.addEventListener('change',()=>{

        let inputVal=entercity.value;
        let url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?q=${inputVal}&key=cb58be19d0d2476da35134140211107`;
         fetch(url).then((res)=>console.log(res))
         .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
     })
```

Comment: I hope this will help you!!

Comment: No, it's not working . Now it's not even showing me the weather.

Comment: @shaikh_sanan_007 I have made some little changes try again!!

Comment: It's working but, now it's showing me the previous city plus this new city I searched for . please help me. image link----> https://prnt.sc/1arlfgr

Comment: @shaikh_sanan_007 I can see there is one more answer  so finally do you still have doubts?

Comment: Hope! I could help you Thankyou!!